# How do I revert mesh to original in Edit mode after finalizing shapekey?

Tags: edit-mode, shape-keys

It gets me every time.
I create new shape key, set value to 1.0 in Object mode , go to Edit mode and play with my mesh. Shape key is done and ready, I can see it working when changing shape key value from 0.0 to 1.0 in Object mode. But I have forgotten to rig my mesh and now Edit mode is locked with my last modification from shape key of 1.0. Is there any way to revert my mesh in Edit mode to the state when it is on shape key value 0.0 ? Or is there any way to prevent this situation from happening when making shape keys ?

Comment: Edit mode will show you whichever shape key you have selected.  If you want to go back to editing Basis, select Basis in the list.  The values of shapekeys does not affect anything in edit mode; the only thing that matters is which shapekey you have selected.

Comment: I had impression, that no matter what shapekey I selected Edit mode was always frozen, but now I tried it again, with moving shapekeys up and down, and Edit mode was refreshed, Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In object properties you should create two shape keys. Don’t edit the first one. That’s your base. Use the second to create your modified shape. Switch between them by selecting from the shapekey list in the property panel.

Comment: First shape key is named Basis by default, I don't edit it, I create another shapekey and edit it. Described issue happened when modifying non-basis shapekey, and when I switch between Basis and this shapekey mesh only changes visually in object mode, but edit mode is still locked in state of shapekey 1.0

Comment: Ok, You were right in the end, I must have not been selecting them properly before, thank You